# Currency restrictions on entry/exit to Norway

Tags: international-travel, money, norway

I am traveling from the US to France, but my flight has a short lay-over in Oslo; can someone explain the currency restriction for entry/exit and whether it applies to travelers passing through.

Edit - Thank you for the answers! I was indeed asking about the money question, and am happy to hear it is a max not a min, as I'm traveling on a shoestring!

Comment: What do you mean by "currency restriction"? Also, what kind of crazy route is that.

Comment: @CMaster He is probably flying with Norwegian and transiting in Oslo.

Comment: @CMaster And what exactly is not clear about the question? He is asking about any currency restrictions when entering or exiting Norway and wether they apply for transiting passengers. I am not sure what's not clear about that.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I wasn't clear what "the currency restriction" is. I'm still not - your guess as to the amount of money you have to report - is one possible interpretation, but I'm far from sure it is the right one.

Comment: I would have thought he meant to say "current restrictions" and is just asking about whether he'd need to deal with immigration and customs at the layover site. I wondered the same thing last year on a stopover from Miami to Madrid to London.  On layover flights through the US, you definitely go through customs at the first US airport or at preclearance locations in Canada\Caribbean), but I do not believe I had to in Madrid, instead waiting until London.  But with the more complex relationship between Norway and the EU, the answer is uncertain to me if that's what is actually being asked for.

Answer (score 19):

When entering or leaving Norway with more currency than the equivalent of NOK 25,000 (appr. USD 3,000), you have to provide a declaration to the Norwegian customs. You can find a more detailed description of the procedure at their 
[web page on this subject](http://www.toll.no/en/goods/currency/).

If you are only transiting between international flights in Oslo, you are however for the purpose of custom's regulations *not* entering Norway. As you are transiting to an intra-schengen flight to France, you will go through immigration check in Norway, but not through customs.

Answer (score 6):

You are not entering Norway, so you are not subject to any currency restrictions; however you will be crossing into Schengen so you'll pass through immigration.

However, to combat money laundering any combination of currency that is in excess of EUR 10,000 (when converted) should be declared at your final destination.

If you do not declare it and are caught later, you may end up forfeiting the entire amount (not just the value greater than 10,000 EUR).

The [relevant regulation (PDF)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2005:309:0009:0012:EN:PDF) has the following to state about it:

> Any natural person entering or leaving the Community and carrying cash
>   of a value of EUR 10 000 or more shall declare that sum to the
>   competent authorities of the Member State through which he is entering
>   or leaving the Community in accordance with this Regulation. The
>   obligation to declare shall not have been fulfilled if the information
>   provided is incorrect or incomplete.

Further,

> ‘cash’ means: (a) bearer-negotiable instruments including monetary
>   instruments in bearer form such as travellers cheques, negotiable
>   instruments (including cheques, promissory notes and money orders)
>   that are either in bearer form, endorsed without restriction, made out
>   to a fictitious payee, or otherwise in such form that title thereto
>   passes upon delivery and incomplete instruments (including cheques,
>   promissory notes and money orders) signed, but with the payee's name
>   omitted; (b) currency (banknotes and coins that are in circulation as
>   a medium of exchange).

Comment: When entering France (or other EU countries), the limit is EUR 10,000 (not USD).

Comment: Moreover, if the OP is carrying more than USD 10,000 (less than EUR 10,000 at the moment) he must declare that to American authorities *on exit.*